# Can't disable Google Analytics page_view events

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

After setting `send_page_view: false` , google analytics still keeps sending automatic `page_view` events, even tho I tried to do that manually

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-*********"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "G-*********", {
        send_page_view: false,
      });
    </script>
```

withTracker.jsx

```
export default (WrappedComponent) => {
  const trackPage = (page) => {
    if (page) {
      window.gtag("event", "page_view", {
        page_path: page.location.pathname,
        page_title: getTitleFromPathname(page.location.pathname),
      });
    }
  };

  const HOC = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => trackPage(props), [props.location]);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return HOC;
};
```

Route example:

```
 <Route path="/404" component={withTracker(NotFound404)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on the fact that you are using a Google Analytics 4 Property ID (G-XXXXXXXX), while the React Analytics package in question works for Universal Analytics. I suggest you create a Universal Analytics Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case for me using Google Analytics 4 [release 2022.08.05](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320?hl=en).

You can install [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)
 and add `debug_mode: true` to `gtag('config')` params to see in the console what exactly happens.

I didn't need to do this but it's also [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318326/2771889) to turn off history event tracking in Enhanced Measurement settings.